# Running two applications in QtCreator 3.6

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator

I am developing two apps that interact with each other over network.

They belong to the same subdirs project and I used to run them from the same instance of Qt Creator without any problems. E.g. I used the following usecases:

- Run 1st app, then run 2nd app
- Debug 1st app, then run 2nd app
- Debug 2nd app, then run 1st app

All three cases worked just fine in all versions of Creator I've ever worked with.

But in the Qt Creator 3.6.0 I see a different behaviour: the 1st app is immediately closed when I start the 2nd app. This is really inconvenient, is it a bug in Qt Creator?

Let me show on a simple example. My simple sample project with two apps: [image: apps]

When I am debugging the 1st app and press Run for 2nd app Qt Creator briefly shows the following window, then 1st app is closed and 2nd is launched.

[image: message box]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a new feature in Qt Creator 3.6. Go to the Build & Run panel in Qt Creator's preferences, then in General you have a combo box beside "Stop applications before building". You can change there the behavior of that feature.

Thread also available on the [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/63295/)